# Re-initialize a javascript function object by variable

Tags: javascript, object

This one is something that is fairly easy to do in PHP and I find my self in a situation where it would come in handy, but I do not believe the PHP trick will work.

Basically I want to use a variable passed from a function within an object to then reinitialize that object using the child (defined by the variable).

```
var View = function(){
    var fn = this;

    fn.load = function(name){
        return new name();
    }
}
var view = View.load('titleView');
```

This is a very early work on it, so forgive the fact that it looks so strange (still need to tinker more with the concept). But overall it should roughly show the concept.

Is there a way to basically recreate the current functions instance with a new function? To do this in the aspect I am thinking of I will need to use a variable rather then pass the new object. Is this possible? I am sure in some form it has to be. Any ideas/pointers? Google has been failing me since I am not sure of the right keywords for this.

EDIT:
should also show the idea behind the "titleView" class

```
var titleView = function(){}

titleView.prototype = new View;
```

Comment: Just a note: Feel free to completely rip apart the code I have so far if it feels more natural to change the thought process behind it. Still a very early concept (or old and I am just blind).

Comment: So in the end `view` should be a new instance of `titleView`?

Comment: basically for titleView it will use prototype to inherit the other functions within view as well so `titleView.prototype = new View;`. PHP uses `$` specifically for variables but javascript does not, making me thing this approach is "wrong" or "misguided".

Comment: if you want to do inheritance here is a [blog post](http://blog.slaks.net/2013-09-03/traditional-inheritance-in-javascript/) by one of the S.O. members. Maybe that will help you in determining what you will need to do.

Comment: More like dynamic inheritance I guess, with a variable I can easily adjust it on the fly, then reinitialize the "view". The reason I use a  function rather then a normal object is to be able to use prototype to create new objects that have the same "base" functions but with a few extra/modified ones. But thank you for the link, I will read it over ^^.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is via some kind of factory that can produce the types of views you are wanting.  Something like this:

```
var View = (function() {
    var registry = {};

    return {
        register: function(type, fn) {
            if (typeof registry[type] === 'undefined') {
                registry[type] = fn;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        },

        load: function(type) {
            return new registry[type]();
        }
    };
})();

var titleView = function() {
    this.name = 'titleView';
};
var subTitleView = function() {
    this.name = 'subTitleView';
}

View.register('titleView', titleView);
View.register('subTitleView', subTitleView);

var view = View.load('titleView');
console.log("Created view type: " + view.name);

view = View.load('subTitleView');
console.log("Created view type: " + view.name);
```

This would give the following (*allowing you to recreate `view` variable on the fly*):

```
// Created view type: titleView
// Created view type: subTitleView
```

If you try to do it the way your example is going, you'll have to use subclasses like so:

```
function Base() {
    this.name = "Base";
    this.load = function(fn) {
        fn.apply(this);
    }
}
function Other() {
    Base.apply(this, arguments);
    this.name = "Other";
}

var view = new Base();
console.log(view);

view.load(Other);
console.log(view);

// => Base { name: "Base", load: function }
// => Base { name: "Other", load: function }
```

However, with this method, after calling `view.load(Other)`, your view will still retain whatever properties/methods it had prior to calling load (*which may not be what you want*).

Comment: Perfect! nice explanation too. This allows the `load` function to be dynamic without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

think this is what ur asking

```
var View = function(){
  this.load = function(name){
  return  name;
  }
}
var myView = new View;
var v = myView.load('titleView');
alert(v);
```

Comment: you will still get a _"string is not a function"_ error

Comment: your fiddle/and edited code are just returning back the string

Comment: pass in obj get out obj, your example passed in str

Comment: My example? this isnt my question... i am just letting you know the mistakes in your code, if you show passing in a string whoever sees this answer will think they should be able to pass a string. Also note even if you pass an object your current code will still just be returning it back, i think you want `return new name;` Not that it matters as OP wants inheritance and this does not do any type of inheritance

Comment: that's kinda beyond my scope friend, but i dig the question, will watch this one ....